# Implementing a generic factory

Tags: java, generics, factory, interface-implementation

I am trying to design a factory for a pluggable interface. The idea is that once you have your factory instance, the factory will return the appropriate subclasses for that particular implementation.

In this case, I am wrapping a third party library that uses a String to represent an ID code, rather than subclasses. Therefore, in the implementation that wraps their library, every implementation class has a method `getCode()` that is not explicitly required by the interface API. I am using an `enum` to store this mapping between codes and interface classes.

In nearly all cases, the `getCode()` method is not needed. However, in just a few situations in the implementation package, I need access to that method. Therefore, my problem is that **I would like to have the Factory implementation's signature tell callers that the `getCode` method exists if they have a reference to the specific Factory implementation**.

What follows is a lot of code in my best-effort attempt to digest the situation into an [sscce](http://sscce.org). I know it's very long, but it's simpler than it seems, and one of the words in sscce is "complete".

#### Public API:

```
public interface Factory {
  public <T extends IFoo> T makeIFoo(Class<T> klass);
}

public interface IFoo {
  void doSomething();
}

public interface IFooBar extends IFoo {
  void doBarTask();
}

public interface IFooBaz extends IFoo {
  void doBazTask();
}
```

#### Sample use case:

```
public class SomeClass {
  private Factory myFactory; 

  public void doSomething() {
    IFooBar ifb = myFactory.create(IFooBar.class);
  }
}
```

#### SSCCE version of implementation:

```
interface ICode {
  String getCode();
}

abstract class BaseCode implements IFoo, ICode {
  private String code;

  BaseCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  @Override
  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  @Override
  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Something");
  }
}

class FooBarImpl extends BaseCode implements ICode, IFooBar {
  FooBarImpl(String code) {
    super(code);
  }

  @Override
  public void doBarTask() {
    System.out.println("BarTask");
  }
}

class FooBazImpl extends BaseCode implements ICode, IFooBaz {
  FooBazImpl(String code) {
    super(code);
  }

  @Override
  public void doBazTask() {
    System.out.println("BarTask");
  }
}
```

#### Enum codemapper:

```
static enum CodeMap {
  FOOBAR ("A", IFooBar.class) {
    FooBarImpl create() { return new FooBarImpl(getCode()); }
  },
  FOOBAZ ("B", IFooBaz.class) {
    FooBazImpl create() { return new FooBazImpl(getCode()); }
  };

  private static Map<Class<? extends IFoo>, CodeMap> classMap;
  static {
    classMap = new HashMap<Class<? extends IFoo>, CodeMap>();
    for(CodeMap cm : CodeMap.values()) {
      classMap.put(cm.getFooClass(), cm);
    }
  }

  private String code;
  private Class<? extends IFoo> klass;

  private CodeMap(String code, Class<? extends IFoo> klass) {
    this.code = code;
    this.klass = klass;
  }

  String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  Class<? extends IFoo> getFooClass() {
    return klass;
  }

  static CodeMap getFromClass(Class<? extends IFoo> klass) {
    return classMap.get(klass);
  }

  abstract BaseCode create();
}
```

#### Sample use case within implementation package:

```
public class InternalClass {
    CodeFactory factory;

    public void doSomething() {
        FooBarImpl fb = factory.makeIFoo(IFooBar.class);
    }
}
```

#### Attempt at factory:

This does not specify that the return will always implement `ICode`. But the passed-in interface class DOESN'T implement `ICode`, that's the whole point.

```
class CodeFactory implements Factory {
  @Override
  public <T extends IFoo> T makeIFoo(Class<T> klass) {
    CodeMap map = CodeMap.getFromClass(klass);

    if (map == null) return null; // Or throw an exception, whatever, SSCCE

    return (T) map.create();
  }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: As I explained in my answer I think that what you are doing **is not** a factory, since the code that uses the instance is the one deciding which class to instantiate (so, no decoupling). Anyway to avoid an extended discussion I will delete my answer since it is not convincing to you.

Comment: @PaulBellora You make a good point, but that is a package private method defined in an enum. But you have pointed me to a mistake in the SSCCE translation, I will fix it now

Comment: @SJuan76 the implementation classes are all package private. The method call is `factory.makeClass(SUB_INTERFACE)` not `factory.makeClass(CONCRETE_CLASS)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I was making this too complicated. If I'm going to implement a factory method for each `enum` instance, I may as well just have separate factory methods for each interface.

```
public interface Factory {
    IFooBar createFooBar();
    IFooBaz createFooBaz();
}

class CodeFactory implements Factory {
    public FooBarImpl createFooBar() {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Of course now I have to change the Factory API if there are ever new interfaces, but I expect that will be rare.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be defining a wrapper that implements `IFoo` and the `getCode()` method, and your method would return the intended class in one of such wrappers.

If the wrapped instance has a `getCode` implemented, the wrapper would return its value, return it, otherwise return `null`.